# Change content of tooltipster on initialize

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I have too many link on a page having tooltip, I want to set content of every link's tooltip on initialize time.

Here is following code i am using:

```
$('.help_tooltip').tooltipster({
    theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
    functionInit: function(origin, content) {
        origin.tooltipster('content','testing content');// here i want to call my custom function 
    }
});
```

but when i run this code this giving me error:

```
Uncaught Error: You called Tooltipster's "content" method on an uninitialized element
```

I found in Documentation http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/#functionInitExample we can change text of tooltip on initialization.

Here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/w481vx1g/

Gitub Issue https://github.com/iamceege/tooltipster/issues/317

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working by adding `return`

```
$('.help_tooltip').tooltipster({
    theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
    functionInit: function(origin, content) {
       return "new content';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't [this](http://jsfiddle.net/w481vx1g/1/) do what you want too:

```
$('.tooltip')
    .tooltipster({
        theme: 'tooltipster-shadow',
        content: test()
    });

function test() {
    return $('<span><strong>See</strong> this is the new content.</span>');
}
```

Comment: I know this but in this way i can't access `origin`.

Comment: So you want 2 tooltips?
origin.tooltipster({'content':'testing content'}); could do it